# Jquery Jpages Function doesnt work inside Jquery ui Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cant make a jquery image gallery with pagination inside jquery UI Tabs. The Tab works well but the pagination doesn't work. I used [Jpages](http://luis-almeida.github.io/jPages/) as plugin.

This is my HTML Code:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#info">Info</a></li>
        <li><a href="#menu">Menu</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="info">First Tabs</div>
    <div id="menu>
       <ul id="itemContainer">
          <li><img src="img/thumb1.jpg"></li>
          <li><img src="img/thumb1.jpg"></li>
          <li><img src="img/thumb1.jpg"></li>
          <li><img src="img/thumb1.jpg"></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="holder"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is the Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        show: function(e, ui) {
            $("div.holder").jPages({
                containerID : "itemContainer",
                previous : "Previous",
                next:"Next",
                perPage:6
            });
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: Can you give us the link of your J-query plugin?

Comment: http://luis-almeida.github.io/jPages/. thank for your time :)

Comment: Would you mind editing your post and show us the html code for tabs and provide also a http://jsfiddle.net/ :)

Comment: Kindly press Ctrl+Shift+J and identify what error the console throws.

Comment: is it because of the missing quote in div with id menu tag?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!